# typescript nested object so the properties don't repeat

Tags: typescript

My interface looks like this at the moment. Is it possible to refactor it so properties are not repeated in the two.

```
export interface Navigation {
    name: string;
    roles: Array<number>;
    sublinks: NavigationItem[];
}

export interface NavigationItem  {
    name: string;
    roles: Array<number>;
    url: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export interface NavigationBase {
    name: string;
    roles: number[];
}

export interface Navigation extends NavigationBase {
    sublinks: NavigationItem[];
}

export interface NavigationItem extends NavigationBase {
    url: string;
}
```